# factorizing polynomials

Tags: algebra-precalculus

for example, you have the function $f(x) = \frac{x^2 - 6x + 8}{x-2}$ , is it always the case that when you have an x in the denominator, which makes the denominator and numerator equal to 0, you can factorize the same factor (in this case: (x-2)) in the numerator (in this case (x-2)(x-4))? If so, why is that always the case?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem

Comment: This is true when the numerator and denominator are *polynomial* functions. (It also works for more general functions - so-called "analytic functions" - but in a way that requires some care.)

Comment: But why is that the case? I've read the answer below, but my native language is not english so I find it hard to comprehend, the remainder theorem is also not what im looking for i think @ThomasAndrews

Comment: I wasn't trying to answer your question, just wanted to mention specific language that would make your statement true. For example, it is not true for $\frac{\sqrt{x-2}}{x-2}.$

Answer (score 1):

This follows from the [fundamental theorem of algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra): a root of a polynomial can always be factorized. So If $x_0$ is a root of both the numerator and the denominator, you can write
$$f(x) = \frac{(x-x_0)p(x)}{(x-x_0)q(x)}$$
for some other polynomials $p$ and $q$ and then cancel the factor.

Comment: The factorization property is much simpler than the (nontrivial!) fundamental theorem of algebra. Moreover it holds over arbitrary ring, as opposed to only complex numbers that FTA applies to.

Comment: @pmp I agree with your first point, so a better link would be [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem). I don't think, however, that generality is an issue for this question specifically.